# Downsampling stationary time series data, effect on variance

Tags: time-series, normal-distribution, stationarity

Suppose I have stationary time series data, like this:

[image]

The time series has Gaussian noise around a true mean. If I then take windows of N samples across the series and average them to generate a new serie, How are the variance of the old and new series related?

Answer (score 2):

I would think that the variance of the sum(or mean) would be related to the individual variances and the covariances between them. If each series is independent of the other then the variance of the sum is the sum of the variances. I would take the covariance matrix of the the individual time series (at each point in time) and use http://faculty.madisoncollege.edu/alehnen/EngineeringStats/Variance_of_a_sum.pdf as the basis for my work.